# Python - Classes- Definition

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, python-2.x, definition

I programmed a class aswell as a definition with the backthought the when you,
set everytime a value using class variable you can always recall the total amount by using the definition

```
class Hand():

    def __init__(self, Hand=0):
        self.Hand = Hand

    def getHand(self, neue_Hand):
        self.Hand = neue_Hand

    def set_hand(self):
        return self.Hand

c = Hand()

def Aufruf():
    Total = 0
    Total += c.getHand(0)
    return Total


c.getHand(12)

Aufruf()
```

It changes the value each time, but doesn't accumulate it as it supposed to be.

Comment: You should get used from now on to using English names. It'll be way easier for people out there to understand and help you.

Comment: Are you indenting properly in your code? In the code you've posted here, the indentation is off. You need to indent after method heading and class def

Comment: `c.getHand` returns None - you cannot `+= None` to `Total`.

Answer (score 2):

You've mixed up the functionality in your getters and setters. The getter should return the variable and the setter should set the value.

```
class Hand():

    def __init__(self,Hand=0):
        self.Hand = Hand

    def getHand(self):
        return self.Hand

    def set_hand(self, neue_Hand):
        self.Hand = neue_Hand

    def increment_hand(self, neue_Hand_incremenet):
        self.Hand += neue_Hand_incremenet

c = Hand(10)
c.getHand()
>> 10
c.set_hand(20)
c.getHand()
>> 20    

def Aufruf():
    Total = 0
    Total += c.getHand()
    return Total

Aufruf()
>> 20
c.increment_hand(10)
Aufruf()
>> 30
```

Also as a side note:
If you look closely, you will realise your method `Aufruf` is actually an exact duplicate (logically) of the `getHand()` method. When you instantiate the variable `total = 0` inside the method block of code, this value will ALWAYS be set to 0 when the method is called, meaning the value from `c.getHand()` will ALWAYS just be the value that's returned

Comment: I think i didn't fully express myself, what i want to do is: when i change the value multiple times via c.set_hand() this value will be stored and added uppon previous values in Aufruf. Example i set c.set_hand(10) and after (20), i should get from Aufruf() = 30

Comment: I'll add some changes to the code, but it wil be slightly different than your current setup. The concept of getters and setters should be the same as in my example. I'll add some new code now

Comment: @Roman demoted my answer? The answer you accepted will not work for your code if you just add his new method get_hand_bigger() and still use it with your get_hand() method in Aufruf

Answer (score 1):

Use method addition for changing value, and don't use capital letters or camelCase inside your class.

```
class Hand:
   def __init__(self, 0):
     self.hand = hand
   def get_hand_bigger(self, addition):
      self.hand += addition
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class method `getHand` does not return any value, yet it is being called as such. Try this:

```
def getHand(self, neue_Hand):
   self.Hand = neue_Hand
   return self.Hand
```

Comment: I think i didn't fully express myself, what i want to do is: when i change the value multiple times via c.set_hand() this value will be stored and added uppon previous values in Aufruf. Example i set c.set_hand(10) and after (20), i should get from Aufruf() = 30